# Javascript Global Variable array

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a src js file where I have this code. I need to manage the est_bandwidth array in the script but even if I'm sure of the correct creation I can't see globally. Why? How can I see the array also outside of the function?

```
var maxBandwidth = 8 * 1024 * 1024;        // 8 Mbps
var est_bandwidth = new Array();
function bandwidth(initial_bps, weight_f, weight_s){

this.bps = initial_bps;
this.weight_f = weight_f;
this.weight_s = weight_s;

}

bandwidth.prototype.calcWeightedBandwidth = function(_bps) {

this.bps = parseInt(((this.weight_f*this.bps) + (this.weight_s * _bps))/2)*0.9;  
    if( this.bps > maxBandwidth && maxBandwidth > 0) this.bps = maxBandwidth;
    est_bandwidth.push(this.bps/1024);
    return this.bps;
}
```

Comment: Where is `est_bandwidth` declared? I can't see an initialization - I'd expect this to throw an error.

Comment: I just forgot the initialization in the example, now I've edited the code here but same problem: I see an empty array even if it's not empty.

Comment: Ah, Ok. And this is the whole js file? How do you access it from outside?

Comment: I have an html page where I have <script src="bandwidth.js"></script>

Comment: this bandwidth.js interact with other js and I want to be able to do something like this <script> document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML=est_bandwidth </script>

Comment: And that results in `undefined`? A demo of what you really do might help, as it [worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/X78AC/).

Comment: no the result is empty. if I modify after the declaration with this: est_bandwidth[0]=1;
est_bandwidth[1]=2; I get, in the element "elem" in the html page, [1,2]. so I can see est_bandwidth but only outside the function and I don't know why.

Comment: Then show us the code that tries to display the variable.

Comment: do you mean this? document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML=est_bandwidth;

Comment: Yes. Where is it in the code, when do you call it etc.? We need a self-contained demo of the non-working site, because the statement [works standalone](http://jsfiddle.net/X78AC/)!

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/X78AC/2/ let me know if you need something else. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the very invalid source of http://fiddle.jshell.net/X78AC/2/show/ - jsfiddle is not the best option for a real-world demo. It currently breaks because there is no `DASHplayer` loaded. Could you link to your own server's test page maybe? Do you get any other console errors?

Comment: yes of course! you can find it here http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/js/dashtest-ibmff.html?MPD=http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/js/content/bunny_ibmff_240.mpd but you must add the code that I've shown to you.

Comment: In http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/js/dash-js/bandwidth.js, you did not declare any `est_bandwidth`. Also, there is an exception in the script dash.js - this might break subsequent code.

Comment: Unfortunatly I haven't a server so I linked to you the sample code. I've just taked the code I linked to you and I've modified only bandwidth.js adding the declaration above.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `est_bandwidth` variable outside of the function to make it available globally. Use `var est_bandwidth;`

Comment: I've declared the variable but nothing changed, I see an empty array

Comment: Are you certain that code that is suppose to fill the array with data does actually run? Put an alert just before `est_bandwidth.push` to confirm that.